# SBCL load error for clsql-mysql from quicklisp for version clsql-20110829

Tags: mysql, lisp, sbcl, clsql, quicklisp

For SBCL 1.0.45, using quicklisp to load clsql-mysql, I get an error about "no symbol", which appears to cause the interface to fail to load.  Specifically, the error is:

[package clsql-mysql]

file: /home/blake/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/clsql-20110829-git/db-mysql/mysql-sql.lisp

in: DEFPACKAGE #:CLSQL-MYSQL

```
 (DEFPACKAGE #:CLSQL-MYSQL

   (:USE #:COMMON-LISP #:CLSQL-SYS #:MYSQL #:CLSQL-UFFI)

   (:EXPORT #:MYSQL-DATABASE)

   (:IMPORT-FROM :CLSQL-SYS
                 :ESCAPED
                 :UNESCAPED
                 :COMBINE-DATABASE-IDENTIFIERS
                 :ESCAPED-DATABASE-IDENTIFIER
                 :UNESCAPED-DATABASE-IDENTIFIER
                 :DATABASE-IDENTIFIER
                 :%SEQUENCE-NAME-TO-TABLE
                 :%TABLE-NAME-TO-SEQUENCE-NAME)
   (:DOCUMENTATION "This is the CLSQL interface to MySQL."))
   ;--> EVAL-WHEN 

  ;==>
   (SB-IMPL::%DEFPACKAGE "CLSQL-MYSQL" 'NIL 'NIL 'NIL 'NIL
                     '("COMMON-LISP" "CLSQL-SYS" "MYSQL" "CLSQL-UFFI")
                     '(("CLSQL-SYS" "ESCAPED" "UNESCAPED"
                        "COMBINE-DATABASE-IDENTIFIERS"
                        "ESCAPED-DATABASE-IDENTIFIER"
                        "UNESCAPED-DATABASE-IDENTIFIER"
                        "DATABASE-IDENTIFIER" "%SEQUENCE-NAME-TO-TABLE"
                        "%TABLE-NAME-TO-SEQUENCE-NAME"))
                     'NIL '("MYSQL-DATABASE") '("CLSQL-MYSQL") 'NIL ...)
 caught ERROR:
      (during compile-time-too processing)
       no symbol named "ESCAPED" in "CLSQL-SYS"
```

Has anyone else experienced this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using clsql from outside Quicklisp. Did you download it at some time in the past? What does `(asdf:system-source-directory "clsql")` show?

The clsql-sys that is loadable via Quicklisp *does* have a symbol named ESCAPED.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I decided that there might be package confusion on my part, so I had synaptic uninstall all the lisp functions, and then used quicklisp to install them.  I also updated my sbcl version to the most recent version 51.    Having done all this, I then began reinstalling those items with quicklisp, and, voila, it worked perfectly!  Quicklisp has made this process so much easier.  Thanks